# How to get full-screen graphics canvas?

Tags: graphics, front-end

Is it possible to create a full-screen graphics without any front end elements like cell brackets and scrollbars? The zero approximation can be

```
{{{z, w}, {z, h}}} = FullScreenArea /. (ScreenInformation /. 
     Options[$FrontEnd, ScreenInformation]);
CreateDocument[
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Green], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {w, h} - 1], Red, 
    AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[{100, 100}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, w - 1}, {0, h - 1}}, ImageSize -> {w, h}],
  WindowSize -> Full];
```

As a result I expect a black screen with green border of one pixel width and one red pixel.
I guess some options are missing to do the job, but there are quite many places one could try to put them to, so I expect someone more familiar with this functionality will respond.

Comment: One option is to change `CreateDocument` to `MessageDialog`. Would that be something that's acceptable to you?

Comment: This is much better, but still not the desired result. The goal is to get the _whole_ monitor screen as a canvas.

Comment: How about the options `WindowSize->Full, ShowCellBracket -> False,  WindowFrame ->
"ThinFrame", WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrameElements -> {}`? (or `"Frameless"` instead of `"ThinFrame"`)

Comment: Good one - would also come in very handy for presentations with fullscreen image content which usually drives me back to Powerpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that you would want some sort of flexibility with this. Just setting the window size to full may not be the best solution. If I was doing it I would prefer to be making a notebook with the graphics filling the entire notebook and then toggling full screen with your graphics size to changing accordingly. To do this you need to make the image size dynamic.

```
CreateDocument[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 
    Dynamic@AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]],
  CellMargins -> 0,
  "BlinkingCellInsertionPoint" -> False,
  "CellInsertionPointCell" -> {},
  Saveable -> True,
  ShowCellBracket -> False,
  ShowCellLabel -> False,
  "TrackCellChangeTimes" -> False,
  StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb",
  WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ZoomBox", "MinimizeBox"},
  WindowElements -> {},
  WindowFrame -> "Normal",
  WindowSize -> All,
  WindowMargins -> Automatic,
  WindowTitle -> ""];
```

This is a variation of something I currently use. What happens is that initially your window opens and you control whether it goes full screen via keystrokes. On my system this means Control-Command-F (see screen grab below). When you toggle full screen the graphic expands to fit the screen. Toggle back and it shrinks to its original size. I set `WindowSize->All` initially but you may prefer to give the window a value e.g. `{600,600}`. I have used a plot to illustrate the resizing. You should set your `AspectRatio` to be the same as your full screen otherwise the graphic won't fit to your full screen properly. My screen aspect ratio is 5/8 so:

```
CreateDocument[
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Green], Rectangle[]},
   AspectRatio -> 5/8, 
   ImageSize -> 
    Dynamic@AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]],
  CellMargins -> 0,
  "BlinkingCellInsertionPoint" -> False,
  "CellInsertionPointCell" -> {},
  Saveable -> True,
  ShowCellBracket -> False,
  ShowCellLabel -> False,
  "TrackCellChangeTimes" -> False,
  StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb",
  WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ZoomBox", "MinimizeBox"},
  WindowElements -> {},
  WindowFrame -> "Normal",
  WindowSize -> {640, 400},
  WindowMargins -> Automatic,
  WindowTitle -> ""];
```

Alternatively you could make the aspect ratio dynamic as well. Note that you will see white around the graphic. To remove this set `PlotRangePadding->0`. The grab below shows the notebook prior to going full screen.

[image]

In the screen grab I used `Red, AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]`. If you want to have the point position in pixel units and plot range in pixels then you would need to make some adjustments -- if you want to go down that path I will adjust the code. Personally I think using `Scaled` is better for managing this.

Comment: To make aspect ratio dynamic: `AspectRatio -> All`