# Mathematica Minecraft

Tags: programming, dynamic, graphics3d, eventhandler, development

Some time ago I asked myself: with all these great graphics and interactive capabilities of *Mathematica*, what kinds of 3D games can be implemented in it?  And the answer which came to mind is [Minecraft classic](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic). The scene in this game is almost static, the [first person view](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5649/219) and [controls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17557/219) can be easily implemented, the terrain textures are [freely available](https://www.google.by/search?q=minecraft+textures&hl=ru&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=A7QeUe2ZPMnEswaJnICIAQ&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAQ&biw=1174&bih=642), and the overall functionality does not seem to be complicated... There is even a related [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BlockBuilder/) on the Demonstrations Project!

So, can Mathematica really handle Minecraft classic game functionality?

Comment: Personally I have always found Mathematica extremely wanting when it comes to game-loop like constructs. Naively working out dynamics or updating frames seems like a bad approach, and it's not easy to get down to the lower level functions. Though I'd love to see someone do something like this.

Comment: You know it's funny--I had about the opposite thought.  How easy it would be to implement some nice calculation software and use Minecraft to visualize the results.  Minecraft has all the drawing/graphing abilities, just interface it and learn to look at your data from a new angle (possibly by climing it)

Answer (score 254):

Well, the answer seems to be YES :)

Here is my implementation of Minecraft classic game in Mathematica. Let’s start with some screenshots which were taken during the construction of the final scene which will be displayed an the end of this post.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Features**

- Blocks are creatable and removable
- One texture per block
- Player automatically jumps to the obstacles of one block height and on the blocks which are created directly underneath. You can also try to fall down.
- Simplified selection tracking, which can miss cube corners, is implemented. Anyway it is still quite intuitive and allows to put blocks diagonally.
- Big action range: you can place and remove blocks located far away.

**Controls**

- W-A-S-D: move forward-left-backward-right. By default double steps are used, Shift key enables single step.
- Arrow keys: look up-down-left-right
- Mouse selects current block
- 1…9: select new block type
- B: show blocks selector
- Left mouse click: delete block
- Right mouse click or Space: create block
- R: set respawn position
- Enter: respawn
- X: Save game state
- L: Load game state

**Performance tuning**

**Terrain construction.** Simple random walk terrain generation is implemented. The following parameters can by adjusted:

`prmTERRAINBLOCKSN` – approximate number of terrain blocks

`prmCLOUDSN` – number of clouds. Each cloud consists of random number of blocks.

`prmTERRAINGRAIN` and `prmTERRAINOFFSET` control the landscape properties. On the first picture below `prmTERRAINOFFSET` is 8, and is 3 for the second one.

[image] [image]

**Hardware issues.** On some systems the presence of a *single* opacity directive drastically decreases performance. In this case one can set `prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY` to `True` or/and try to use `prmRENDERINGENGINE=”BSPTree”`.

**Conclusion**

To be honest I am myself surprised how well the final code performs. On average system it easily handles thousands and even tens of thousands blocks. With the growth of this number the “gameplay” becomes too slow.  It is also should be noted that what really matters is the number of faces, because hidden faces are not included in the final Graphics3D, so clustered blocks are preferable.

The result of my first construction session is
[image]

This scene can be downloaded (and loaded from *Mathematica*) from [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=97579589029972382797). Here is the code.

```
prmWORLDWIDTH = 200;
prmWORLDHEIGHT = 100;
prmVIEWERHEIGHT = 2.75;
prmVIEWRANGE = {0.01, 300};
prmMOVESTEP = .95;
prmACTIONRANGE = 300;
prmTRACESTEP = 0.33;
prmVIEWANGLE = 45 Degree;
prmFALLINGPAUSE = 0;
prmVERTLOOKANGLEDELTA = 4.99 Degree;
prmHORLOOKANGLEDELTA = 90 Degree/4.;
prmSKYCOLOR = RGBColor[0.58, 0.77, 0.96];
prmTEXTURESIZE = 16;
prmTERRAINBLOCKSN = 5000;
prmCLOUDSN = 3;
prmFLOORMATERIAL = matSand;
prmRENDERINGENGINE = Automatic;
prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY = False;
prmSMOOTHTERRAIN = True;
prmTERRAINGRAIN = 3;
prmTERRAINOFFSET = 3;

terrainImg = Import["http://i.imgur.com/2uAswvI.png"];
ClearAll["mat*"];
materials =
  {matGrass -> {1, 1},
   matStone -> {1, 2},
   matDirt -> {1, 3},
   matPlanks -> {1, 5},
   matPlate -> {1, 7},
   matBricks -> {1, 8},
   matCobblestone -> {2, 1},
   matBedrock -> {2, 2},
   matSand -> {2, 3},
   matGravel -> {2, 4},
   matWood -> {2, 5},
   matLeaves -> {2, 7},
   matMossStone -> {3, 5},
   matObsidian -> {3, 6},
   matGlass -> {4, 2},
   matWhiteWool -> {5, 16},
   matGrayWool -> {5, 15},
   matDarkGrayWool -> {5, 14},
   matMagentaWool -> {5, 13},
   matPinkWool -> {5, 12},
   matPurpleWool -> {5, 10},
   matBlueWool -> {5, 9},
   matLightBlueWool -> {5, 8},
   matCyanWool -> {5, 7},
   matGreenWool -> {5, 5},
   matLimeWool -> {5, 4},
   matYellowWool -> {5, 3},
   matOrangeWool -> {5, 2},
   matRedWool -> {5, 1},
   matClouds -> {1, 12},
   matSilver -> {2, 8},
   matGold -> {2, 9}
   };

dirVectors = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}};
vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
vertCoords = # - {1, 1, 1} & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 
     0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}};
faceCoords = {{7, 6, 5, 8}, {3, 7, 8, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {6, 2, 1, 
    5}, {5, 8, 4, 1}, {3, 2, 6, 7}};

filename = "save.mmc";


initMaterials[] := Block[{},
   nMat = Length@materials;
   Evaluate[materials[[All, 1]]] = Range[nMat];
   matAir = 0;
   With[{ts = prmTEXTURESIZE},
    textures = 
     ImageTake[terrainImg, ts (#1 - 1) + {1, ts}, 
        ts (#2 - 1) + {1, ts}] &
      @@@ (materials[[All, 2]])
    ];
   textures[[matClouds]] = 
    Image[Array[{1, 1, 1} &, {prmTEXTURESIZE, prmTEXTURESIZE}]];
   ClearAll[transparentQ];
   Do[transparentQ[mat] = 
     MemberQ[{matLeaves, matGlass, matClouds, matAir}, mat], {mat, 0, 
     nMat}];
   If[! prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY,
    textures[[matLeaves]] = 
     ImageData[
       textures[[
        matLeaves]]] /. {{1., 1., 1.} -> {0., .5, 0., 0.}, {r_, g_, 
         b_} :> {r, g, b, 1.}};
    textures[[matGlass]] = 
     ImageData[
       textures[[
        matGlass]]] /. {{1., 1., 1.} -> {5., .5, .1, 0.}, {r_, g_, 
         b_} :> {r, g, b, 1.}};
    textures[[matClouds]] = 
     Array[{1, 1, 1, .75} &, {prmTEXTURESIZE, prmTEXTURESIZE}];
    ];
   ];

initIcons[] := Block[{},
   icons = Graphics3D[{ EdgeForm@None, Texture[#],
        Polygon[# & /@ vertCoords[[#]], 
           VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc] & /@ faceCoords},
       Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 64, 
       Background -> Black] &
     /@ textures;
   setterbar = Column[SetterBar[
        Dynamic[
         palette[[
          curBlockType]], {(palette[[
              curBlockType]] = #) &, (updatePalette[]; 
            DialogReturn[]) &}], #] &
      /@ Partition[Thread[Range[nMat] -> icons], 6, 6, {1, 1}, {}]
     ];
   palette = {matStone, matCobblestone, matBricks, matDirt, matPlanks,
      matWood, matLeaves, matGlass, matPlate};
   curBlockType = 1;
   updatePalette[];
   ];

updatePalette[] := (paletteGfx = Image[
     GraphicsRow[icons[[palette]],
      Evaluate[Frame -> Array[# == curBlockType &, 9]],
      Evaluate[FrameStyle -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness@3]],
      Background -> Black
      ], ImageSize -> 500]);

updateCubes[] := (cucubes = Flatten@cubes;);

saveGame[file_] := 
  Export[file, {pos, viewDir, moveDir, strafeDir, palette, 
     curBlockType, SparseArray@blocks} // Compress, "Text"];

loadGame[file_] := Block[{p, vd, md, sd, pal, cbt, bl},
   If[! FileExistsQ[file], MessageDialog["File not found"]; Return[]];
   {p, vd, md, sd, pal, cbt, bl} = Uncompress@Import[file, "Text"];
   {pos, viewDir, moveDir, strafeDir, palette, curBlockType} = {p, vd,
      md, sd, pal, cbt};
   blocks = Normal@bl;
   dim = Dimensions@blocks;
   {prmWORLDWIDTH, prmWORLDHEIGHT} = Rest@dim;
   initFloor[];
   initCubes[]; updateCubes[]; updatePalette[]; getSelection[];
   FinishDynamic[];
   ];

saveDialog[] := CreateDialog[
   Grid@{{Dynamic["Save to file: " <> filename], 
      FileNameSetter[Dynamic[filename], "Save"]},
     {DefaultButton[saveGame[filename]; DialogReturn[]],
      CancelButton[]
      }}
   ];

loadDialog[] := CreateDialog[
   Grid@{{Dynamic["Load from file: " <> filename], 
      FileNameSetter[Dynamic[filename], "Open", {"mmc" -> {"*"}}]},
     {DefaultButton[loadGame[filename]; DialogReturn[]],
      CancelButton[]
      }}
   ];

showBlockChooser[] := CreateDialog[setterbar, {},
   WindowSize -> 500,
   Background -> Black,
   Modal -> True,
   WindowFrame -> "Frameless",
   TextAlignment -> Center
   ];

initBlocks[] := (
   dim = {prmWORLDWIDTH, prmWORLDWIDTH, prmWORLDHEIGHT};
   blocks = Array[0 &, dim];
   );

initCamera[] := Block[{},
   pos = {1.5, 1.5, prmVIEWERHEIGHT};
   height = Ceiling@prmVIEWERHEIGHT;
   moveDir = {1, 1, 0} // Normalize;
   viewDir = moveDir;
   strafeDir = {1, -1, 0} // Normalize;
   respawnPos = Null;
   currentBlockPos = newBlockPos = Null;
   selection = {};
   viewAngle = 0;
   ];

initFloor[] := (floor = With[{w = prmWORLDWIDTH},
     {EdgeForm[None],
      Texture[textures[[prmFLOORMATERIAL]]],
      Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, w, 0}, {w, w, 0}, {w, 0, 0}},
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {w, 0}, {w, w}, {0, w}}]}
     ]);

initCubes[] := Block[{g, type, pointers, faces},
   cubes = {Texture@#} & /@ textures;
   cubePointers = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{0, 0, 0}}] & /@ textures;
   g = ParallelMap[{#, createCube[#]} &,
     Position[blocks, b_ /; b > 0]];
   Scan[({pointers, faces} = Transpose@#;
      type = blockAt@First@pointers;
      cubes[[type]] = cubes[[type]]~Join~faces;
      cubePointers[[type]] = cubePointers[[type]]~Join~pointers;
      ) &,
    GatherBy[g, blockAt@First@# &]
    ];
   ];

processFalling[] := Block[{i, j, k}, While[
    ({i, j, k} = blockPos[pos])[[3]] > height && 
     blocks[[i, j, k - height]] == 0,
    pos -= {0, 0, 1}; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[prmFALLINGPAUSE]
    ]];


lookHor[da_] := ({moveDir, strafeDir, viewDir} = 
    RotationTransform[da, {0., 0., 1.}] /@ {moveDir, strafeDir, 
      viewDir});
lookVert[da_] :=
  If[Abs[viewAngle + da] <= Pi/2,
   viewAngle += da;
   viewDir = RotationTransform[da, strafeDir]@viewDir
   ];

move[dv_, n_Integer] := Do[move@dv, {n}];
move[dv_] := Block[{newpos, i, j, k, space},
   newpos = pos + dv;
   If[! inRange@newpos, Return[]];
   {i, j, k} = blockPos@newpos;
   If[k + 1 > prmWORLDHEIGHT, Return[]];
   space = blocks[[i, j, (k - height + 1) ;; k + 1]];
   Which[
    And @@ Thread[Most@space == 0], pos = newpos,
    First@space != 0 && (And @@ Thread[Rest@space == 0]), 
    pos = newpos + {0, 0, 1}
    ];
   processFalling[];
   ];


processKeyboard[] := (
  Switch[CurrentValue["EventKey"],
   "W", move[prmMOVESTEP  moveDir],
   "S", move[-prmMOVESTEP moveDir],
   "A", move[-prmMOVESTEP strafeDir],
   "D", move[prmMOVESTEP strafeDir],
   "w", move[prmMOVESTEP  moveDir, 2],
   "s", move[-prmMOVESTEP  moveDir, 2],
   "a", move[-prmMOVESTEP  strafeDir, 2],
   "d", move[prmMOVESTEP  strafeDir, 2],
   "q", pos += {0, 0, 1},
   "b", showBlockChooser[],
   "r", (respawnPos = pos),
   "x", saveDialog[],
   "l", loadDialog[],
   " ", addCurrentBlock[],
   "1", curBlockType = 1; updatePalette[],
   "2", curBlockType = 2; updatePalette[],
   "3", curBlockType = 3; updatePalette[],
   "4", curBlockType = 4; updatePalette[],
   "5", curBlockType = 5; updatePalette[],
   "6", curBlockType = 6; updatePalette[],
   "7", curBlockType = 7; updatePalette[],
   "8", curBlockType = 8; updatePalette[],
   "9", curBlockType = 9; updatePalette[]
   ];
  getSelection[];
  )

actions = {
   {"MouseDown", 1} :> deleteCurrentBlock[],
   {"MouseUp", 2} :> (addCurrentBlock[]; getSelection[]),
   "MouseMoved" :> getSelection[],
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> lookHor[prmHORLOOKANGLEDELTA],
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> lookHor[-prmHORLOOKANGLEDELTA],
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> lookVert[prmVERTLOOKANGLEDELTA],
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> lookVert[-prmVERTLOOKANGLEDELTA],
   "ReturnKeyDown" :> If[respawnPos =!= Null, move[respawnPos - pos]],
   "KeyDown" :> processKeyboard[],
   PassEventsDown -> False
   };

inRange = And @@ Thread[{0, 0, 0} < # <= dim] &;
blockAt = blocks[[Sequence @@ #]] &;
setBlock = (blocks[[Sequence @@ #1]] = #2) &;
setMouse[expr_] := MouseAppearance[expr, "Arrow"];
blocksCount[] := Count[blocks, b_ /; b != 0, {3}];
facesCount[] := Count[cubes, Polygon[__], {3}];
blockPos = Ceiling;


neighborList[p_] := Block[{cf},
   cf = If[transparentQ@blockAt@p,
     (blockAt[#] == matAir) &,
     (transparentQ@blockAt[#] &)
     ];
   Quiet[Flatten@
     Position[p + # & /@ dirVectors, _?(inRange[#] && cf[#] &), {1}, 
      Heads -> False]]
   ];

createCube[coords_] :=
  Polygon[coords + # & /@ vertCoords[[#]], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc] & /@ 
   faceCoords[[neighborList@coords]];

setCube[coords_, type_] := (
  AppendTo[cubes[[type]], createCube[coords]];
  AppendTo[cubePointers[[type]], coords];
  )

addBlock[bp : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}?inRange] := (
   setBlock[bp, palette[[curBlockType]]];
   setCube[bp, palette[[curBlockType]]];
   updateNeighbors@bp;
   );

neighborCoords[p_] := 
  Quiet[Cases[
    p + # & /@ dirVectors, _?(inRange[#] && blockAt[#] != matAir &), 
    1]];

updateNeighbors[p_] := Block[{np, locs},
   np = neighborCoords@p;
   locs = 
    ParallelMap[Position[cubePointers, #, {2}, Heads -> False] &, np];
   (cubes[[Sequence @@ (First@#1)]] = createCube@#2) & @@@ 
    Transpose@{locs, np};
   ];

deleteBlock[bp : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}?inRange] := 
  Block[{loc},
   loc = Position[cubePointers, bp, {2}, Heads -> False];
   setBlock[bp, 0];
   cubePointers = Delete[cubePointers, loc[[1]]];
   cubes = Delete[cubes, loc[[1]]];
   updateNeighbors@bp;
   ];

addCurrentBlock[] :=
  If[newBlockPos != blockPos@pos,
   getSelection[];
   addBlock@newBlockPos;
   move@{0, 0, 0};
   getSelection[];
   updateCubes[];
   ];

deleteCurrentBlock[] := (
   getSelection[];
   deleteBlock@currentBlockPos;
   getSelection[];
   processFalling[];
   updateCubes[];
   );

getSelection[] := Block[{flag, found, chain, mp},
   flag = False;
   mp = MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts", Null];
   currentBlockPos = newBlockPos = Null;
   selection = {};
   If[mp === Null, Return[]];
   v = Normalize[Subtract @@ mp];
   If[v.viewDir < 0, v = -v];
   found = (flag = (Last@# < 0 || blockAt[blockPos@#] != 0)) &;
   chain = NestWhileList[
     # + prmTRACESTEP v &,
     pos,
     (And @@ Thread[{0, 0, -1} < # < dim]) && (! found@#) &,
     1, Ceiling[prmACTIONRANGE/prmTRACESTEP]];
   If[flag,
    currentBlockPos = blockPos@chain[[-1]];
    selection = {EdgeForm@{Black, Thick},
      FaceForm[None],
      Cuboid[currentBlockPos - 1, currentBlockPos]
      };
    If[Length@chain > 1, newBlockPos = blockPos@chain[[-2]]];
    ];
   ];

(*World generation*)

randomWalkPattern[nb_, m_, d_] := 
  Module[{n = prmWORLDWIDTH, q, i0, j0, i1, j1, field, applyAt, 
    offset, ok, p, next},
   field = Array[0 &, {n, n}];
   applyAt = 
    Function[{i, j}, field[[i - m ;; i + m, j - m ;; j + m]] += 1];
   offset = RandomInteger[d {-1, 1}, {2}] &;
   ok = (m < #1 <= n - m) && (m < #2 <= n - m ) &;
   next = (While[! ok @@ (q = # + offset[]), q]; q) &;
   p = Floor[{n, n}/2];
   Do[applyAt @@ p; p = next@p, {Round[nb/(2 m + 1)^2]}];
   If[prmSMOOTHTERRAIN,
    ListConvolve[BoxMatrix[2]/25, field] // Round,
    field]
   ];

createTerrain[bc_] := Block[{field},
   field = randomWalkPattern[bc, prmTERRAINGRAIN, prmTERRAINOFFSET];
   With[{h = Min[field[[##]], prmWORLDHEIGHT]},
      blocks[[#1, #2, 1 ;; h]] = 
       RandomChoice[{matGravel, matStone}, h];
      blocks[[#1, #2, 1]] = RandomChoice@{matBedrock, matDirt};
      If[1 < h < RandomInteger@{4, 9},
       blocks[[#1, #2, h - 1 ;; h]] = matDirt;
       If[RandomChoice@{True, False}, blocks[[#1, #2, h]] = matGrass];
       ];
      ] & @@@ Position[field, b_ /; b > 0, {2}];
   ];

createClouds[nClouds_] := 
  Block[{cloud, ww = prmWORLDWIDTH, wh = prmWORLDHEIGHT, i, j, h},
   Do[
     cloud = randomWalkPattern[RandomInteger@{200, 1000}, 1, 2];
     {i, j} = RandomInteger[{-ww, ww}/2, 2];
     h = RandomInteger@{wh/2, wh};
     Quiet[blocks[[#1 + i, #2 + j, h]] = matClouds] & @@@ 
      Position[cloud, b_ /; b != 0, {2}],
     {nClouds}
     ];
   ];


initMaterials[];
initIcons[];
initBlocks[];
createTerrain[prmTERRAINBLOCKSN];
createClouds[prmCLOUDSN];
initFloor[];
initCubes[];
initCamera[];

updateCubes[];

scene = Graphics3D[{Dynamic@floor, EdgeForm@None, Dynamic@cucubes, 
    Dynamic@selection},
   ViewVector -> Dynamic@{pos, pos + viewDir},
   ViewRange -> prmVIEWRANGE,
   PlotRange -> All,
   Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Boxed -> False,
   BoxRatios -> Automatic,
   ImageSize -> 
    Dynamic@AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize],
   ViewAngle -> prmVIEWANGLE,
   Background -> prmSKYCOLOR,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   Epilog -> {crosshair, Inset[Dynamic@paletteGfx, Scaled@{.5, .05}]}
   ];

crosshair = {White, AbsoluteThickness@2,
   Line[{Scaled@{.49, .5}, Scaled@{.51, .5}}],
   Line[{Scaled@{.5, .49}, Scaled@{.5, .51}}]
   };

CreateDocument[
  EventHandler[
   setMouse@Style[scene, Selectable -> False, Editable -> False],
   actions
   ],
  CellMargins -> 0,
  ShowCellBracket -> False,
  ShowCellLabel -> False,
  "TrackCellChangeTimes" -> False,
  WindowElements -> {},
  WindowFrame -> "Normal",
  WindowSize -> Full,
  "BlinkingCellInsertionPoint" -> False,
  "CellInsertionPointCell" -> {},
  WindowMargins -> Automatic,
  WindowTitle -> "Mathematicraft",
  Background -> Black,
  Editable -> False,
  NotebookEventActions -> actions,
  TextAlignment -> Center,
  Deployed -> True,
  RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> 
     prmRENDERINGENGINE}
  ];

blocksCount[]
facesCount[]
```

The code has been tested on *Mathematica* version 8.0.4 and WinXP and Win7 operation systems. Further improvements are appreciated as well as the comments about the code organisation and style. Thank you!

---

### *Update*

First of all I'd like to thank the community for the votes and comments. In this update I will make some considerations about the performance of the above code ([here is the link](http://pastebin.com/CjFZ3MpW) to it on Pastebin for convenience).

As I see from the comments, the speed of current implementation is both hardware and version specific. There are two main characteristics: the smoothness of motion and the speed of scene update after block creation or removal. I guess that the smoothness depends on graphics card, and the update speed on both the processor and GPU.

On my working G860 3Hz Intel processor with integrated Intel HD graphics and Win7 OS I have the following:

- The default scene with 5000 terrain blocks and 3 clouds is smooth enough for comfortable movement *with disabled transparency*. It speeds up a bit when no dynamic selection is displayed (when I point to the sky).
- The update speed is approximately 1-2 seconds per operation.
- The overall performance deteriorates significantly with enabled transparency. One way out is to set `prmCLOUDSN=0` since it is clouds what is transparent on the default scene.
- With 20 000 terrain blocks and disabled opacity the movement is still pretty smooth, the scene update takes 2-3 seconds.
- No performance differences between versions 8 and 9 on my system.
- The scene I've constructed began with 1000 terrain blocks, no clouds (I added them manually) and no transparency. With this inital settings the scene updates momentally and is comfortable for construction. Honestly I am not sure about how transparency is handled on different systems, but on the system with an old discrete GeForce card it seemed to work faster than on integrated GPUs.

So my advices on performance improvement still are:

- Use `prmTERRAINBLOCKSN` and `prmCLOUDSN` wisely. Try to set them to zero at all.
- Try `prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY=True`
- Point to the sky when move

---

Comment: Well you knocked this question out of the park on the first pitch...

Comment: Could you give a download link for the code too?  It's painful to copy and paste something this long.

Comment: I was also wondering about how smooth the performance is on your machine.

Comment: Jesus! That is quite superior! You seem to know what the real dope is

Comment: @Szabolcs Use my [answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/5) :) (this is also built into the senotebook)

Comment: NiiIIIiIIiiiIIce

Comment: @rm-rf Or run this : `NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[Import@ "http://i.stack.imgur.com/QHOSk.png","Byte"],"NB"]` :DD

Comment: They are going to have to lock out comments on this one.  Before that happens let me be yet another to say... Whoa!

Comment: Created an account on the Mathematica boards just to upvote this post.

Comment: This is amazing and mind boggling. But is very slow in my PC on Mathematica 9. What is the hardware requirement for this to run smoothly?

Comment: @Szabolcs, PlatoManiac: Are you using the default scene with 5000 terrain blocks? Have you tried set prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY=True (see the post)?

Comment: @faleichik you are right in Mathematica 8 its much much faster and quite smooth. But in 9 its too slow!

Comment: For a truly fullscreen experience, add `DockedCells -> None` to the options at the end to remove the Mathematica infobar.

Comment: @faleichik What function(s) exactly run slower in 9 than in 8? Did you test what part of code is the most time consuming for cpu/gpu?

Comment: I don't see any textures, it's completely white for me. It's slow as well but still, awesome! I did not think mathematica could do that.

Comment: @crobartie Curremtly I don't have version 9, so it is difficult to say where is the bottleneck.

Comment: @Markus The textures are downloaded from imgur, so most probably the internet connectivity is not enabled in your Mathematica. Try to turn it on.

Comment: @faleichik I'm using the default scene and I did set `prmDISABLETRANSPARENCY=True`.  The speed is similar in 8 and 9.  Also, I was testing on a new machine (2.6 GHz i7).  It is usable with the speed it runs here, but it would be very painful to build what you have built, by hand.  One difference I noticed between 8 and 9 is that the bloc outline is one block higher in 9 than in 8.

Comment: Please could really try it a lot more easily if they didn't have to select the whole code block.  Why don't you give an alternate way of getting the code, e.g a [pastebin](http://pastie.org/pastes/6220584/text)?

Comment: @Szabolcs see the update. Sorry for delay, Pastebin seems to be a really good way to share code.

Comment: Very Nice code I like it but very slow in Mathematica 10.0...

Comment: runs very bad on my 3 GHz core i7 and GTX 770 LOOOL O_O...that is very bad

Comment: I would like to see redstone implemented, and then build a computer in game capable of running Mathematica.

Comment: Crashed Mathematica 10.3 :(

Comment: Crashed in mma v10.4

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66486755/scene.mmc Dropbox link is dead

Comment: Doesn't work in Mathematica 12

Comment: @lama12345 Reloaded to gofile, check it out please. And sorry I don't have v.12, so I cannot see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you @faleichik it works in Mathematica 12, just couldn't get it to work without the scene file