# How can I rewrite my game without using Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, interface

**Snake Games**

```
Module[
{dir = {-1, 0}, x = -1., y = 0., snake = Table[{i, 0}, {i, 0, 4}],
gameover = False,
target = {RandomInteger[17] - 9, RandomInteger[17] - 9},
timecount = 0,
score = 0},
Manipulate[
If[
 Mod[timecount, 5] == 0 && u != {-1, -1} && gameover == False,
x = u[[1]];
y = u[[2]];
dir = If[
 y >= x,
 If[y >= -x, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}],
 If[y >= -x, {1, 0}, {0, -1}]
 ];
 If[
  MemberQ[snake, 
    snake[[1]] + dir] || (snake[[1]] + dir)[[
     1]] < -10 || (snake[[1]] + dir)[[1]] > 
    9 || (snake[[1]] + dir)[[2]] < -10 || (snake[[1]] + dir)[[2]] > 
    9,
  gameover = True;
  score = Length[snake] - 5
  ];
 If[
  (snake[[1]] + dir) == target,
  target = {RandomInteger[17] - 9, RandomInteger[17] - 9},
  snake = Most[snake]
  ];
 PrependTo[snake, snake[[1]] + dir]
 ];
timecount++;
Framed[
 Graphics[
 If[
  False == gameover,
  Append[
   Table[Rectangle[i, i + {1, 1}], {i, snake}],
   Rectangle[target, target + {1, 1}]
   ],
  {Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}], 
   Text[Style[" Game over! ", FontSize -> 36], {0, 3}, 
    Background -> White], 
   Text[Style[" Score: ", FontSize -> 24], {0, 0}, 
    Background -> White], 
   Text[Style[score, FontSize -> 24], {0, -2}, Background -> White]}
   ],
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0
   ],
  FrameMargins -> 0
 ],
{u, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, ControlPlacement -> Right
]
]
```

It is not convenient for the user to play this game in the above form. So how can I rewrite it without using `Manipulate`, but using other functions that can provide a better user interface?

Comment: @Nasser，It is not convenient for manipulate function to operate the snake game.You could copy the codes to run it.At that time ,you can understand my qusetion.

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation for [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) and [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html). Then start out trying smaller constructions, then try to build this game again, and come back when you know more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Some useful ideas for keyboard control [in the amazing Minecraft Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19669/mathematica-minecraft)

Comment: @Nasser.Sorry，I can't translate it clearly.Anyway，Thank you!

Comment: A generic answer: Use [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html) for your variables, perhaps [`Panel`, `Grid`, etc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LayoutAndTables.html) for layout, place your controls or write your own with [`EventHandler`, etc.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DynamicInteractivityOverview.html) -- these links are guides to the functions that can help you do what you want.  But you'll have to decide what you want (or ask an expert).

Comment: In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17317/245), I used `DynamicModule` to create a little snake following the mouse. Maybe it's an eel, though. Not sure.

Comment: @amr.I have writen my snake game's code that ues your guide.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've actually done a good job considering you are only using `Manipulate`. Here's a simplified snake game using `Dynamic`:

```
snake = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}};
dir = {0, -1};

directions = {
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (dir = {0, 1}),
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (dir = {0, -1}),
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (dir = {-1, 0}),
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (dir = {1, 0})};

EventHandler[
 Graphics[
  Dynamic[Rectangle /@ snake],
  PlotRange -> 5],
 directions]

While[True, Pause[.5];
 snake = Most[snake]~Prepend~(snake[[1]] + dir);]
```

Here I put the `Dynamic` inside the `Graphics` expression, rather than wrapping the whole `Graphics` with a `Dynamic`. This works because `Graphics` is designed to let it work, and it does make a difference (in general) if you need performance.

I recommend you read the documentation for [Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) (especially the "Details") and the [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) tutorial. It's kinda boring but it's useful.

Another thing I should point out, that wasn't obvious to me at first, is that `Dynamic` uses `Set`, quite explicitly. What this means in practice is that `Dynamic` works, for example, with array locations:

```
array = {1, 2, 3};
Dynamic[array]
Slider[Dynamic[array[[2]]]]
While[True, Pause[.5]; array[[2]] = RandomReal[]]
```

As well as for function downvalues such as `f[2]`. This makes the programming easier for larger controls, such as matrix controls and the like.

Comment: ,Thanks very much.I will use your method to rewrite my game.

Answer (score 8):

Writing games using dynamic interactivity in mathematica is an amusing subject! I will vote up your post for this. But I agree with others that it is hard to answer your question, you should work out minimal example for us first.

Below I am giving my code for tetris. I recognize, it is a nonminimal answer, but it is working and can be useful for you. Controls are with arrow keys. To make controls working, make the focus on the panel, e.g. click "MatTetris!". Enjoy.

```
numFigures=6;speed=6;
gLen=16;gWidth=10;bckgColor=Black;bckgColor2=Gray;figColor=Red;patColor=Blue;
fig[1]={{1,-1},{1,0},{0,0},{0,1}};
fig[2]={{-1,-1},{-1,0},{0,0},{0,1}};
fig[3]={{-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}};
fig[4]={{-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},{2,0}};fig[5]={{-1,1},{0,1},{0,0},{0,-1}};
fig[6]={{1,1},{0,1},{0,0},{0,-1}};
mRight={{0,1},{-1,0}};
mLeft={{0,-1},{1,0}};

MovementPossible[where_]:=Block[{altData=Which[
 where=="down",{figData[[1]]+{0,-1},figData[[2]]},
where=="left",{figData[[1]]+{-1,0},figData[[2]]},
where=="right",{figData[[1]]+{1,0},figData[[2]]},
where=="rotleft",{figData[[1]],(mLeft.#)&/@figData[[2]]},
where=="rotright",{figData[[1]],(mRight.#)&/@figData[[2]]}
]}
,(Count[patData,Alternatives@@((altData[[1]]+#)&/@figData[[2]])]==0)&&(Count[altData[[1,2]]+altData[[2,All,2]],x_/;x<1]==0)&&(Count[altData[[1,1]]+altData[[2,All,1]],x_/;((x<1)||(x>gWidth))]==0)];
Move[where_]:=(figData=Which[
 where=="down",{figData[[1]]+{0,-1},figData[[2]]},
where=="left",{figData[[1]]+{-1,0},figData[[2]]},
where=="right",{figData[[1]]+{1,0},figData[[2]]},
where=="rotleft",{figData[[1]],(mLeft.#)&/@figData[[2]]},
where=="rotright",{figData[[1]],(mRight.#)&/@figData[[2]]}
]);
AddFigureToPattern:=(patData=Union[patData,(figData[[1]]+#)&/@figData[[2]]];figData={{0,0},{}});
AddingFigurePossible:=(Count[patData,Alternatives@@(({Round[gWidth/2],gLen-1}+#)&/@prefigData)]==0);
AddFigure:=(figData={{Round[gWidth/2],gLen-1},prefigData};prefigData=fig[RandomInteger[{1,numFigures}]]);
DeleteLines:=Block[{lineCount=0,ic=1},
        While[ic<=gLen,
                If[Count[patData,{_,ic}]==gWidth,
                patData=DeleteCases[patData,{_,ic}];patData=((#/.{xx_,yy_/;yy>ic}:>{xx,yy-1})&/@patData);++lineCount;--ic,
                ++ic];
                ]
            Score[lineCount]];
Score[lC_]:=Which[lC==1,totScore+=1,
                lC==2,totScore+=3,
                lC==3,totScore+=6,
                lC==4,totScore+=10];
GameOver:=(CreateDialog[{Column[{Style["Game Over!",FontColor->Red,FontSize->18],
Row[{Style["Your score is: ",FontColor->Blue,FontSize->18],Style[totScore,FontColor->Blue,FontSize->18]}]
}],DefaultButton[ResetGame;DialogReturn[]]}];)
ResetGame:=(patData={};prefigData=fig[RandomInteger[{1,numFigures}]];FigureActive=False;totScore=0;notGamingOver=True)
MainCycle:=If[FigureActive,
    If[MovementPossible["down"],
    Move["down"];,
    FigureActive=False;AddFigureToPattern;DeleteLines;],
    If[AddingFigurePossible,
    AddFigure;FigureActive=True;,
    If[notGamingOver,notGamingOver=False;GameOver];]
];
gameBoard:=EventHandler[
Panel[Row[
{Dynamic@Graphics[{{bckgColor,Rectangle[{0,0},{gWidth,gLen}]},{figColor,Rectangle[#-{1,1},#]&/@((figData[[1]]+#)&/@figData[[2]])},{patColor,Rectangle[#-{1,1},#]&/@patData}},ImageSize->300],
Column[{
Style["MatTetris!",FontColor->Blue,FontSize->18],,Row[{Style["Score:  ",FontColor->Red,FontSize->18],Dynamic@Style[totScore,FontColor->Red,FontSize->18]}],,,Dynamic@Graphics[{{bckgColor2,Rectangle[{-2,-2},{2,1}]},{figColor,Rectangle[#-{1,1},#]&/@prefigData}}],,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,""
},Center]
}]],
{"LeftArrowKeyDown":>If[MovementPossible["left"],Move["left"]],"RightArrowKeyDown":>If[MovementPossible["right"],Move["right"]],"DownArrowKeyDown":>If[MovementPossible["down"],Move["down"]],"UpArrowKeyDown":>If[MovementPossible["rotleft"],Move["rotleft"]]}];

LaunchGame:=(ResetGame;MainCycle;gameBoard);

LaunchGame
While[True, MainCycle; Pause[1 - speed/10]]
```

Comment: ,Thanks very much!