# Generalize WASD Function First Person Viewing

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

How might I generalize the following [WASD question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17557) such that it works with any `Graphics3D` object and includes `q` and `e` for z(up and down) movement?  For example `qweasd[gr_]`.

Please comment if the question is too general or needs editing.  Current [code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fK8Bq9Wy).

Comment: Your question tags seem inappropriate. Code-review doesn't apply because you present no code, and Version-10 doesn't apply because nothing specific to V10 is mentioned.

Comment: @m_goldberg true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

```
Begin["esdf`"];
worldwidth = 300;
prmVIEWERHEIGHT = 2.5;
prmMOUSESENS = 0.01;
prmKEYSENS = 2;

pos = {-146.2715891902948`, -154.52068004641723`, 
   2.5`}(*{0.,-200,prmVIEWERHEIGHT}*);
moveDir = {0.6365371822219685`, 0.7712460149971068`, 0.`}(*{0,1,0}*);
viewDir = moveDir;
strafeDir = {0.7712460149971068`, -0.6365371822219685`, 0.`}(*{1,0,0}*);

cube = {Gray, EdgeForm[None], CapForm[None], 
   Tube[{{-150, -150, 0}, {-50, 0, 0}, {50, 0, 0}}, 20], 
   Blue // Lighter, 
   Translate[
    ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}, "PolygonObjects"]~
     Scale~3, {0, 0, 6}]};
floor = {Texture@ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GreenMarble"}], 
    EdgeForm@None, 
    Polygon[{{-w, -w, 0}, {-w, w, 0}, {w, w, 0}, {w, -w, 0}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
        1}}]} /. w -> worldwidth;

rotTrans := Function[x, Evaluate[RotationTransform[x, {0., 0., 1.}]]];
mp0 = MousePosition[];

mouse := (mousePos = MousePosition[];
   {mouseDx, mouseDy} = mousePos - mp0;
   mp0 = mousePos;
   viewDir = 
    RotationTransform[-prmMOUSESENS mouseDy, strafeDir]@viewDir;
   {moveDir, strafeDir, viewDir} = 
    rotTrans[-prmMOUSESENS mouseDx] /@ {moveDir, strafeDir, viewDir};);

keys := Switch[CurrentValue["EventKey"], ".", 
   pos += prmKEYSENS moveDir, "e", pos -= prmKEYSENS moveDir, "o", 
   pos -= prmKEYSENS strafeDir, "i", pos += prmKEYSENS strafeDir];

actions = {"MouseMoved" :> mouse, "KeyDown" :> keys};

SetOptions[
  CreateDocument[{Dynamic@
     EventHandler[
      Style[Graphics3D[{{Gray, EdgeForm@None, CapForm@None, 
          Tube[{{-150, -150, 0}, {-50, 0, 0}, {50, 0, 0}}, 20], 
          Blue // Lighter, 
          Translate[
           ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}, 
             "PolygonObjects"]~Scale~3, {0, 0, 6}]}, floor}, 
        ViewVector -> {pos, pos + viewDir}, ViewRange -> {0.1, 300}, 
        Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Full, 
        Background -> LightBlue, PlotRangePadding -> 0], 
       Selectable -> False, Editable -> False], actions]},
   CellMargins -> 0, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
   "TrackCellChangeTimes" -> False, WindowElements -> {}, 
   WindowFrame -> "Normal", WindowMargins -> Automatic], 
  NotebookEventActions -> actions];

End[];
```